# Why was the French patent FR2553560 lapsed two times in 1998?

Tags: license

I suspect that the registration of Japanese version of the patent was transferred to AREVA Japan from assignee JAERI and maintained during the lifetime of the patent. French version of the patent was lapsed due to the nonpayment of patent fee on the basis of the contract beteween JAERI and AREVA. The French version of the patent is only recorded as lapsed in Google patent two times, 8/14 and 9/25 in 1998. What is the reason for that? Can I get any information about contract between JAERI and AREVA from France Patent Office?

Comment: Please answer my question as far as possible

Comment: We’ve answered the best we can. Google isn’t reliable, and no one but the companies knows what is in their agreements.

Comment: I suppose that Japanese patent office may have the contract paper of the transfer of the Japanese version of the patent between the assignee JAERI and new owner AREVA JAPAN.

Comment: JAERI can license AREVA without transferring ownership. If that were the case then I don't think the patent office would know or care about it. To be truthful I don't understand your need for the information since the patent has expired.

Comment: JAERI refuses to pay for the patent. I, the invebtor have not got any money for the expired patent. I convinced that the invention is of a great value for nuclear fuel recycling. I have the duty of knowing  and making recognize the fact to stupid JAERI and Japanese.

Comment: Akihiko, for most business, if you invent something while an employee, the company owns the patent. I have 87 patents with my name listed as an inventor and none of them pay me royalties. Unless your employment agreement stipulates differently, you have no financial interest in the patent. If you should have been compensated, then you next step is to consult with a lawyer. There is really nothing else this site can help you with. Best of luck.

Comment: I have  had the justice with JAERI on this event last year. I have lost for the trial. You could see the trial document in google patent.  However, they made clear that JAERI must pay some maney(5% of total pay)for the valuable patent if the patent is excuted or sold. They refused to show the evidence of selling or the transferring the patent right to AREVA

Comment: As I said, perhaps a lawyer can help. Unfortunately this site can't.